# Uniform distribution marginal density and conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

Let $X$ be uniform on $\left[0,1\right]$, and given $X$, let $Y$ be uniform on $\left[X^{2},X\right]$. Find the marginal density of $Y$ and find $E(X|Y)$.
My attempt was $$f_{y|x}(y|x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x-x^{2}}, \text{if $0\leq x^{2}\leq y\leq x\leq 1$}\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and $f_{y}(y)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) \,dx$ and $f(x,y)=f_{y|x}(y|x)\times f_{x}(x)$, where
$$f_{x}(x)=\begin{cases} 
1, & \text{if x $\in \left[0,1\right]$}\\
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Hence $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x-x^{2}},& \text{if $0\leq x^{2}\leq y\leq x\leq 1$}\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Finally $f_{y}(y)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x-x^{2}} \,dx$ but there exists improperness the integral is undefined at $0$ and $1$ therefore I could not make progress.

Comment: The integral for $f_Y(y)$ is from $y$ to $\sqrt y$.

Comment: It seems logical becuse $\sqrt {y}$ is larger thank you.